# Rearrange a C# list of objects when one property has duplicates

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list defined like this in C#:

```
public class Author  
{  
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public string Book { get; set; }    
} 

List<Author> originalAuthorList = new List<Author>
{
    new Author{ Name = "Bob", Book = "Bob's First Book" },
    new Author{ Name = "Dan", Book = "Dan's First Book" },
    new Author{ Name = "Dan", Book = "Dan's Second Book" },
    new Author{ Name = "Tom", Book = "Tom's First Book" }
};
```

How could I rearrange the list to be like this?

```
List<Author> newAuthorList = new List<Author>
{
    new Author{ Name = "Bob", Book = "Bob's First Book" },
    new Author{ Name = "Dan", Book = "Dan's First Book, Dan's Second Book" },
    new Author{ Name = "Tom", Book = "Tom's First Book" }
};
```

In other words, when an author has several books, I don't want there to be multiple items in the list for that author.  I want each author to appear in the list one time, with all of the author's books listed in the book field.

Comment: We have on Stack Overflow already hundreds, if not thousands, of examples of how to group data in C# and consolidate one or more properties for each group. E.g. see duplicate. In your case, you may like `string.Join()` for creating the new `Book` value for each group.

Comment: I have edited my original question so that each item in the list has 4 fields.  How can I group the items by Id and include all 4 fields in the new list?  Other questions I saw only had 2 fields.

Comment: Please do not change the fundamental aspects of your question after it's been posted. If you have some new facet to your problem that you still need help with, post a new question. In your new question, make sure that you include a [mcve] that shows what you've done so far, explain what you've tried so far to solve the new problem, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: I tried to post a new question, but was told that I wasn't allowed to do so, since I just posted this question yesterday.

Comment: The site does have built-in constraints to limit the activity, especially of new users. You will have to wait. Which should not be a problem; Stack Overflow is not the right place to find help if there is any urgency to your need. The point of the site is to accumulate over time a database of useful information, not to act as a timely answer desk for programmers.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____2__) and then [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) to project the results into the correct type, for example:

```
List<Author> newAuthorList = originalAuthorList
    .GroupBy(
        a => a.Name, // Group by name
        a => a.Book) // Select the book as the element
    .Select(g => new Author
    {
        Name = g.Key,
        Book = string.Join(", ", g) // Join the books together
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, arrange the data into a lookup table.

```
var lookup = originalAuthorList.ToLookup
(
    x => x.Name,
    x => x.Book
);
```

Now you have a list of names, each of which is associated with a list of authors matching the name.

From there, the solution is easy:

```
var newAuthorList = lookup.Select
(
    x => new Author
    (
        Name = x.Key,
        Book = string.Join( ",", x.Select( y => y.Book) )
    )
);
```